# Multisite: How to bypass wpmu_signup_user_notification and add my own notification logic?

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I'm trying to change the $admin_email used as the "from" address when new people register for my WPMS site. I see from the wpmu_signup_user_notification docblock that you can bypass and override the function but I don't know how. The pertinent section of the docblock reads:

- Filter {@see 'wpmu_signup_user_notification'} to bypass this function or
- replace it with your own notification behavior.

How do I use a filter to replace this function with my own notification logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy. All I needed was to inject the appropriate add_filter() and follow it up with my custom function. That's all I needed to completely override the original function. So sweeet.

To bypass `wpmu_signup_user_notification()` and use my own custom function I needed the following:

```
add_filter('wpmu_signup_user_notification', 'gqa_signup_user_notification', 10, 4);
```

And in my custom function I actually just copied the entire function from `ms-function.php` and only changed the part I needed to change (the $admin_email variable), but I could have entirely rewritten it had I needed to.

I don't know what WPMU functions behave in this way, or why they didn't just make them pluggable, but whatevs, I'm happy to have this kind of control.

FWIW I was also able to do the same with `wpmu_welcome_user_notification`.